# Generate Linq query from type and property of passed lambda expression

Tags: entity-framework, lambda

```
    int getMaxValue<SomeEntity>(x => x.SomePropertyOfSomeEntity)

    int getMaxValue<SomeEntity>(Expression<Func<SomeEntity, int>> SomePropertyOfSomeEntity)
    {
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)SomePropertyOfSomeEntity.Body;
        var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;

        DBContext db = new DBContext();


        //somehow convert property info and SomeEntity into this query, using db for the context

        int maxValueOfProperty = (from x in db.SomeEntity
                                  select x.SomePropertyOfSomeEntity).Max();
        return maxValueOfProperty;
    }
```

Comment: Why you need property info at all? The passed expression can be used directly for `Select` or `Max`. e.g. `return db.Max(SomePropertyOfSomeEntity);`

Comment: that doesn't work. I would have to do db.SomeEntity.Max(SomePropertyOfSomeEntity); but that doesn't work, since SomeEntity is just a type

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed the generic argument. Then just add `class` constraint and use `return db.Set<SomeEntity>().Max(SomePropertyOfSomeEntity);`

Comment: seems to work, if you write that up I'll mark it as the answer